# Why cannot I import 'pandas_udf' in Jupiter notebook?

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I run the following code in Jupyter notebook, but get ImportError. Note that 'udf' can be imported in Jupyter.

`from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf`

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'pandas_udf'

Anyone knows how to fix it? Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your version of spark ?

Comment: It is pyspark 2.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you start jupyter notebook by itself, rather than start pyspark with jupyter notebook, which is following command:

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook" pyspark
```

If your jupyter notebook server process are running from another machine, maybe you want to use this command to make it available to all IP addresses of your sever.

**(NOTE: This could be a potential security issue if your server is on a public or untrusted network)**

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 " pyspark
```

I will revised my answer if the problem still persist after you start jupyter notebook like that.